# How to enable Shutter selection option in ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ubuntu-21.04, shutter

I have installed shutter by using this command in ubuntu 21.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter                     
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt install shutter
```

or

```
sudo snap install shutter
```

shutter installed but the selection option to take screenshot of something specific is disabled.
[image]

I have used it earlier with ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 but it does not work in 21.04

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Ask it somewhere else.

Comment: tHis iS nOt a pRogRamMinG qUeStiOn